# Adding extra information to mule loggers

Tags: java, spring, logging, mule, spring-aop

I would like to add some correlation id for each requests and have it shown in the log messages automatically. How do I add an extra value to `<logger />` and its variations more or less automatically?

I have tried:

1. Spring aop cut into `LoggerMessageProcessor.process(MuleEvent event)`, but it the event doesn't contain the logged message
2. Spring aop cut into `LoggerMessageProcessor.setMessage(String msg)` which would contain the message, but for some reason the method isn't invoked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<flow name="add-correlation-id">
        <scripting:component doc:name="Script">
        <scripting:script engine="groovy">
            <![CDATA[
                String correlationId=message.getInboundProperty('x-request-id');
                if(correlationId==null || correlationId.length() == 0){
                    correlationId = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                }
                message.setSessionProperty('requestID',correlationId);
                org.apache.log4j.MDC.put('x-request-id',correlationId);
            ]]>
        </scripting:script>
    </scripting:component>
</flow>
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually was able to find a solution by myself, but this can definitely be used to simplify it.